# What kind of questions can be asked for a Embedded Software Engineering job interview?

Tags: interviewing, technical-interviews, software-engineering

Firstly, I am a newbie on this site. If there is anything wrong with my post I would appreciate any feedback. I have looked at previous questions, but I could not see a related one.

I just graduated in Electrical and Electronics engineering. I have a job interview next week for embedded software engineering. What kind of questions can be asked in the interview in technical aspects? Can the questions asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7579389/is-bit-twiddling-a-good-test-for-embedded-engineer) be asked? I know that I cannot swallow four years of knowledge in a couple of days. I am just curious about what to expect since I have limited interview experience.

If it helps, I know and can code in C, C++, Assembly, and Verilog. However, I have not coded any big project for a company.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are an EE or EEE, it would be expected that you know how to use scopes and equipment such as JTAGS effectively.  (It would be **expected**, but I had EE degrees and almost *no ability with such equipment*).  So if you can do practical tasks with equipment like this, it is a big plus for your chances.  If not, emphasize firmware as a software-engineering offshoot.

I informally define firmware as software that runs on a non-traditional computer such as an embedded controller.

Also, part of engineering is design ability, the ability to read diagrams, and provide documentation.

They know that you are just coming out of the university, so their expectations should be reasonable.

If you have had internist experience, or hobbyist experience, that too is a plus, and be sure to include it in your self-description.

ADVICE: If there is a negative question (such as describe a problem with a co-worker) I would not treat it at face-value, but emphasize that you faced a problem, did well with it, and everyone was happy, as that is more likely to help you get the job.  (Since this is largely about attitude, honesty can be retained here, as long as you yourself have a positive attitude).

Best wishes for a long and successful career!

Comment: I appreciate your answer deeply. In today's racing world everything can make you think underqualified. After seeing your answer, my confidence has risen since I have an experience or two in the things you mentioned. Thank you for your kind wishes.

Answer (score 4):

Embedded software engineering is a broad field.  I'd expect questions about your understanding of microcontrollers, especially the family that this company uses.

There are multiple options as far as programming microcontrollers but the most common today is still C/C++.

It's doubtful that you, as a new grad, are going to be responsible for a "big project".  More likely you will be a part of a team that is developing a product and you will be responsible for some smaller part of it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will keep in mind the things you said.